# what does projective space of nxm matrices mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The question is as follows: For $n, m ≥ 1$ let $Pnm−1$ be viewed as the projective space of $n × m$-matrices. Prove
that the set of matrices of rank exactly $k$ is a quasi-projective variety. We denote this
quasi-projective variety by $Rk ⊆ Pnm−1$.

But geometrically, what does projective space of $n × m$ matrices mean?

Comment: Presumably it means that matrices $A,B$ in this space are taken to be equivalent ($A\sim B$) if $A=\lambda B$ for some $\lambda \neq 0$. (What a _quasi_-projective variety is, I don't know and you should google.)

Comment: A quasi-projective variety is the complement of a closed subvariety in a projective variety. Every affine variety and every projective variety is quasi-projective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix form a vector space $V$ so you can take the associated projective space $\Bbb P(V)$. Inside this space, set $A_k$ of matrices of rank $\leq k$ is closed, the equations being vanishing of some minors, so it follows that the set $X = A_{k} \backslash A_{k-1}$ of matrices of rank exactly $k$ is a quasi-projective varity.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand your explanation given above. But can you tell me how this projective space would exactly look like? For example, projective space P1 is considered to be collection of lines through the origin . So how should one visualise the projective space of matrices ?

Comment: Any projective space $\Bbb P(V)$ is the collection of line through this origin of $V$. Here, $\Bbb P^1$ means that $V = \Bbb C^2$, but it works for **any** vector space in particular for the vector space of all matrices $M_{m \times n}(\Bbb C)$. If you want to understand projective space geometrically, there is a very nice decomposition $\Bbb P^n = \Bbb A^n \sqcup \Bbb A^{n-1} \sqcup \dots \sqcup \Bbb A^1 \sqcup \{pt\}$.

Comment: Thank you once again!   I guess i need to think this through.. So this decomposition basically tells me that projective variety is n+1 affine patches glued together. So geometrically how would the affine space of n x m matrices look like?

Comment: Sure ! It is $n+1$ affine patches of different dimension : first you take $\Bbb A^n$, then you glue $\Bbb A^{n-1}$ and you continue like this. For geometric interpretation, my best advice would be to just work with algebraic definition, which is working pretty well. This is a vector space of dimension $mn$ and its elements are linear functions $f : \Bbb C^m \to \Bbb C^n$.

Comment: Okay! It seems to be a little more clear now.Thank you!

Comment: @Nivedita : sure you are welcome ! (also don't forget to activate the little green mark next to the question, so the question is considered as answered :-) )